# All desktop settings are messed after logout

Tags: 11.04, kde

I do some trivial modifications to my KDE desktop such as changing wallpaper and adding a few widgets. After I logout and then login again all my modifications are lost.

Additionally, the panel is missing and no windows is displayed for the started applications (only a rectangle of the window is shown when i pres Alt-Tab).

After some experiments I discovered that I can get bring back the panel and windows if I play with Activities, but it only lasts till the next logout.

I have no idea how to approach this issue, so any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I solved the problem by

1. Turning on "Start with empty session" from  System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Session Management
2. Deleting all plasma-related files (~/.kde4/share/config/plasma*)
3. Log out
4. Log in and and turn off "Start with empty session"

The hint is from [panosk answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=886728)